# Using an enum inside enum in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, enums

```
enum KINDS {
  STATIC = 1,
  FIELD,
  ARG,
  VAR
}

enum ALL_KINDS {
  STATIC = 1,
  FIELD,
  ARG,
  VAR,
  NONE
}
```

How can I reuse the first enum inside the second one?

Comment: By "re-use" you mean you want `ALL_KINDS` to include the entries, with the same values, from `KINDS`?

Comment: Yup @DaveNewton.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK, extending enums is [under consideration](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17592), in the meantime you can use const objects instead:

```
const KINDS = <const>{
  STATIC: 1,
  FIELD: 2,
  ARG: 3,
  VAR: 4
};

const ALL_KINDS = <const>{ ...KINDS, NONE: 5 };
```

There are also other workarounds in the above thread.

If you want this type to be checked, note that from the type perspective, a numeric `enum` is equivalent to `number`:

```
enum KINDS {
  STATIC,
  FIELD,
  ARG,
  VAR
}

declare function func(name: string, type: string, kind: KINDS): any;

func('foo', 'bar', KINDS.ARG); // compiles
func('foo', 'bar', 99); // compiles too (?)
```

If you use an object as suggested above, you can also enforce strict type checking by creating a type for all possible values of that object:

```
const KINDS = <const>{
  STATIC: 1,
  FIELD: 2,
  ARG: 3,
  VAR: 4
};

type KIND_VALUE = typeof KINDS[keyof typeof KINDS]

declare function define(name: string, type: string, kind: KIND_VALUE): any;

define('foo', 'bar', KINDS.ARG); // compiles
define('foo', 'bar', 99); // doesn't compile
```

This is a bit more verbose, but then you have your type actually checked.

Comment: In the method declaration, define(name: string, type: string, kind: KINDS) {}, it shows an error 'KINDS' refers to a value , but is being used as a type here. That is way I used enum.